# What is the reason for $g_{tt}g_{rr}=-1$?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, metric-tensor, reissner-nordstrom-metric

Both Reissner Nordstrom and Schwarzschild solutions in GR exhibit the property that  $g_{tt}g_{rr}=-1$.

What can we deduce from this property in terms of the gravitational field?

Comment: This is not a covariant equation so it is a property not of gravitational field but of particular parametrization of it (coordinate system).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Despite my earlier comment, I think question is actually well posed: Schwarzschild coordinates possess some properties that make them 'natural' for static spherically symmetric spacetimes, so the condition of $g_{tt} g_{rr}=− 1$ would be indicative of the feature of a geometry.

And so here is the answer, from the 'pedagogical note':

- Jacobson, T. (2007). When is $g_{tt} g_{rr}=− 1$?. *Classical and Quantum Gravity*, 24(22), 5717, [doi](https://doi.org/10.1088/0264-9381/24/22/N02), [arXiv](https://arxiv.org/abs/0707.3222).

> ... this commonly occurring feature arises if and only if the radial 
>   null-null components of the Ricci tensor (which are equal) vanish; equivalently, if the restriction of the Ricci tensor to the $t$-$r$
>   subspace is proportional to $g_{μν}$. When the Einstein equation is satisfied this condition holds for the stress-energy tensor, implying that the radial pressure is the negative of the energy density. An equivalent condition is that the coordinate $r$ is an affine parameter on the radial null geodesics.

Comment: That’s a really nice find!